# Best practice for including data persistence inside integration flow (SpringIntegration)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

My question is related to finding a best practice to include data persistence inside an integration flow while returning the Message object so that it can be further processed by the flow.

Let's consider the following flow:

```
  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
    return flowDefinition ->
        flowDefinition
            .filter(filterUnwantedMessages)
            .transform(messageTransformer)            
            .wireTap(flow -> flow.trigger(messagePayloadPersister)) <--- here is the interesting part
            .handle(terminalHandler);
  }
```

The wide majority of cases, instead of the wireTap I have seen in some projects, a Transformer is used to persist data, which I do not particulary like, as

the name implies transformation of a message, and persistence is something else.

My wish is to find out alternatives to the wireTap, and a colleague of mine proposed using @ServiceActivator:

```
  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
    return flowDefinition ->
        flowDefinition
            .filter(filterUnwantedMessages)
            .transform(messageTransformer)            
            .handle(messagePayloadPersister)
            .handle(terminalHandler);
  }

  
  @Component
  class MesssagePayloadPersister {
    @ServiceActivator  <--- interesting, but..
    public Message handle(Message<?> msg) {
       //persist the payload somewhere..

       return message;
    }
  }
```

I like the flow, it looks clean now, but also I am not 100% happy with the solution, as I am mixing DSL with Spring.

Note: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler is not good because the handle method returns void so it is a terminal part to the flow. I need a method that returns Message object.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-store.html

Answer (score 1):

Need to understand what you are going to do with that persisted data in the future.

And what information from the message you are going to store (or the whole message at all).

See this parts of documentation - may be something will give you some ideas:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management.html#message-store

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management.html#metadata-store

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/message-transformation.html#claim-check

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/core.html#persistent-queuechannel-configuration

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter

With the last one you may need to consider to use a `publishSubscribeChannel()` of the Java DSL to be able to store in the DB and have a second subscriber to continue the flow.